# How to read user input while in a inotifywait while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, stdin, inotify, inotifywait

When I use inotifywait and then read within the while loop something breaks. I never receive the input the the script just breaks. This is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
scriptDir=$(pwd)

get_input() {
   read userInput
   echo $userInput echod
}

inotifywait -m -e modify,create,delete  $scriptDir | while read alterationDetails
do
    echo "something changed"
    get_input
done
```

Ideally instead of "get_input" I'd like to be able to call another script which takes input in that while loop. For example:

```
eval "node inputCatcher.js"
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `stdin` is already linked to the pipe. How about `read userInput < /dev/tty`.

Comment: Thank you. This works for bash but I guess I'll have to adjust my other scripts.